# Admob Mediation to Flurry for an AIR App

Tags: air, admob, ads, flurry, air-native-extension

I am using the Native Extension from http://www.milkmangames.com/blog/tools/ to display AdMob Fullscreen Ads (Interstitial) in a Game. The Ads from Admob work fine.

Now i would like to use Flurry Ads using Admob Mediation. Here is what i did:

1. Create Application and AdSpace in Flurry
2. Setup the Mediation in Admob using Project API Key and Ad Space Name from Flurry.
3. Set the eCPM of Flurry higher then Admob (also tried lower)

Still only Admob Ads are shown. Am i missing something? Has anyone gotten mediation to work (maybe even with AIR Native Extension) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have the Flurry SDK and and Admob-FLurry mediation adapter in your app also.

You need to wait about 5 minutes for any mediation config changes to propagate.

And then Flurry has to have some ads to show you. It's possible that they have none for your device in your area at this point in time.

Comment: Hi William,
thanks for your answer. I have Flurry SDK integrated, but i do not have the "Admob-FLurry mediation adapter". The Adapter seem to be available at https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/mediation-networks will try it out